# How can I display a viewpager for one size class, and a regular layout for another?

Tags: ios, swift, size-classes

I have been tasked with making an iPhone-only app universal. One of the screens is a detail view that consists of an info view (with metadata) and a document view (that shows a pdf).

Now, on the iPhone-version, the info view and document view are inside a `UIScrollView` subclass with a property for each of the `UIViewController` instances, and a bunch of logic to make it look nice:

```
class ITViewPager: UIView, UIScrollViewDelegate {

    var infoVC:DocumentMetaController?
    var documentVC:DocumentViewController?
    ...

}
```

The xib file for the detail screen contains this `ITViewPager` which is initialised in the `DetailViewController`.

For iPad, I need a different layout where the info and document view are placed next to each other (not even using the ITViewPager at all). I would really like to use size classes, since the "regular width" class is exactly what I need. What would be the most elegant way to go about this? If I simply uninstall the ITViewPager for this size class, it will still be loaded and fully initialised. Feels like there should be a better way?

Comment: you could create just a container view in IB and lazily create the ITViewPager when the "regular width" size class becomes active and manually add it to the container view. also (de-)activate layout constraints appropriately.

Comment: Pity something as easy as this requires coding, I was hoping to be able to do more in IB. Nevertheless, thanks a lot for your suggestion!